# Firebase "once" event does not return promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

In official document of firebase https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html. It writed

> Return Value
>
> Returns a Promise that can optionally be used instead of the successCallback and failureCallback to handle success and failure.

But in my example code there are no promise return when call once function

```
fb.once('value', function(snapshoot){
    snapshoot.forEach(function(snap){
    var book = new Book(snap);
    $scope.bookList.push(book);
    $scope.$apply();
  });
})
//following lines below cause error because of no promise returned.
.then(function(){
    console.log('promise called');
});
```

Please see full code at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7e4j77q7/5/

What i'm doing wrong here? How can i let once function return promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using older version of `firebase`, the DOC you are referring has `2.4.2` version & you had older version `1.0.11`

Comment: Thanks you. I changed firebase to version 2.4.2 and it work now